# NGINX reverse proxy to ASP.NET Core web app 404 static files

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, kestrel-http-server, asp.net-core-6.0

Have a basic hello world ASP.NET Core web app with the only modifications being to `program.cs` -> removed httpsredirect and hsts so it's set up for http.

Published to an Ubuntu server under `/var/www/hello_world` with static files under `/var/www/hello_world/wwwroot`. The app sits behind a NGINX reverse proxy to the kestrel server listening on http://127.0.0.1:5000.  Everything works fine for the main endpoint, but everything else (css|js|lib|.ico) returns a 404 unless I specify the static files directory in a separate location directive:

```
location ~* /(css|js|lib) { root /var/www/hello_world/wwwroot; }
```

I've tried setting up my `nginx.conf` in both an upstream configuration:

```
    server  {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/hello_world.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/hello_world.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://dotnet;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
    upstream dotnet {
    zone dotnet 64k;
    server 127.0.0.1:5000;
}
```

and a straight-forward proxy_pass:

```
server  {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name helloworld.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/hello_world.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/hello_world.key;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    # returns 404 for static files unless I have this
    location ~* /(css|js|lib|ico) {
        root /var/www/hello_world/wwwroot;
    }
}
```

I can see the shell info from dotnet that the directory structure is correct in the request that is getting passed to kestrel, but kestrel returns a 404 unless I add the location in the nginx.conf. Since none of the guides either from NGINX or Microsoft have this location block I'm assuming I configured something incorrectly. The way I assumed it would work is everything going to that server block with the location / would get passed to kestrel which the ASP.NET Core app would have the directory structure mapped and return the static files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else that runs into this, the issue was because I was running `dotnet hello_world.dll`
from an ssh shell in the  `/etc/nginx` directory which in Linux makes it the working directory for that process and in turn, the content root path for the ASP.NET application.  The fix is to run the `dotnet hello_world.dll` from the `/var/www/hello_world` directory or specify the working directory when making the service.

Thanks @marc_s for the edit.  I'll remember to do better next question.

Comment: Thank you so much for coming back and posting this answer. It was exactly my issue and I feel stupid now.
Why isn't there any warning about this when you launch the webapp? it should print the wwwroot folder

Comment: No worries, I hate coming across a post that details my exact problem - only to find "solved" with no explanation. Not sure why that isn't documented, but I felt stupid when I learned what it was doing too.  I'm pretty novice in the Linux world though.  Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above configuration I think I have set the working directory in my service but still my css/js files are not loading. Following is my service

```
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/BlissTechMind/ 

ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/BlissTechMind/BlissTechMind.dll
```

[image]